# Hosting a Blog and App on a single Azure Web Site?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I like the idea of using Azure to host a Wordpress Blog.

I currently have an Azure Website that I'd like to add a blog to.  Ideally I can create another website for the blog, and then have blog.mysite.com always show the contents of myblog.azurewebsites.net.  Would this be possible?

I can have my domain registrar forward/mask from blog.mysite.com, but if there's a way to do it without masking, any info on getting that done would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you create a web site, Windows Azure provides a friendly
>   subdomain on the azurewebsites.net domain so your users can access
>   your web site using a URL like http://.azurewebsites.net.
>   However, if you configure your web sites for Shared or Standard mode,
>   you can map your web site to your own domain name.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/

Comment: Can this be set to a subdomain?

Comment: @RobVious - yes, no problem. Your custom domain can be blog.mysite.com.

Comment: sweet!  I gave it a shot and it complained about the site needing to be the base address, but I'll try again and post back.  Thanks for the help